Circular icon on share sheet header
I wish to display different icons on share sheet header. The default icon is app icon which is square with rounded rectangle. This looks good and as expected. However if I have a circular icon, then the icon shows up with white square background with circular icon on it.
When icons are round, I just wish to show circular icon without white square background. How can I achieve it?
Code which adds details for the header:
func activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> LPLinkMetadata? {
    let metadata = LPLinkMetadata()
    metadata.title = self.sheetTitle ?? ""
      
// Icon which gets displayed on share sheet header.
    if let icon = UIImage(named: "user-profile") {
        metadata.imageProvider = NSItemProvider(object: icon)
    }
        
    return metadata
}

Code for entire Share Sheet, if needed:
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import LinkPresentation

class ShareSheet {
    static let shared = ShareSheet()
    typealias Callback = (_ activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, _ completed: Bool, _ returnedItems: [Any]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void

    let applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil
    let excludedActivityTypes: [UIActivity.ActivityType]? = nil

    func open(subject: String, content: String, sheetTitle: String? = nil, heaaderImage: UIImage? = nil, callback: Callback? = nil) {
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [MessageWithSubject(subject: subject, message: content,
                                                                                     sheetTitle: sheetTitle, heaaderImage: heaaderImage)],
                                                  applicationActivities: applicationActivities)
        controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivityTypes
        controller.completionWithItemsHandler = callback
        UIWindow.getTopViewController()?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class MessageWithSubject: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    let subject: String
    let message: String
    let sheetTitle: String?
    let headerImage: UIImage?

    init(subject: String, message: String, sheetTitle: String? = nil, heaaderImage: UIImage? = nil) {
        self.subject = subject
        self.message = message
        self.sheetTitle = (sheetTitle?.isBlank ?? true) ? Bundle.main.applicationName : sheetTitle
        self.headerImage = heaaderImage ?? Bundle.main.appIcon
        super.init()
    }

    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return message
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
        let activityTypeId = activityType?.rawValue ?? ""

        // Include the subject at the beginning of the message string, for apps that don't ask for the subject string directly.
        // This works around an issue where the Gmail app doesn't request the subject string itself.
        // Also, include it for the Notes app, since it provides context to the link URL.
        if (activityTypeId == "com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension") || (activityTypeId == "com.google.Gmail.ShareExtension") {
            let combined = subject + "\n\n" + message
            return combined
        }

        return message
    }
    
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> String {
        return subject
    }
    
    func activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> LPLinkMetadata? {
        let metadata = LPLinkMetadata()
        metadata.title = self.sheetTitle ?? ""
        
        if let icon = UIImage(named: "user-profile") {
            metadata.imageProvider = NSItemProvider(object: icon)
        }
        
        return metadata
    }
}

How icon looks with this code and my circular icon :
 | 
I want the icon to look circular like in Apple Maps i.e. without white square background:


Is it possible that Apple simply uses an image with the same background color as the sheet?
